# Regarding Http Callouts in Salesforce

Tags: soap-api, soap

What is the Use of Mock Response in Soap User interface why it is Necessary,while Processing the Request and automatically the Response came to SoapUi then why we Need Extra Mock Response I am New to Salesforce Please Explain or anyone Guide Me for the Explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a class that generates a mock response is only necessary to be able to [Test Web Service Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm). You can create your web service call code and run it without ever writing a class that generates a mock response.

However it is desirable to have tests for all your code and the platform mandates that overall 75% of the lines of code are touched (covered) by tests when you deploy to production. So if you choose to test or are forced to test your HTTP callout code, the mocking mechanism is the way to go (as tests that make callouts without setting up a mock will always fail).

(Or you can resort to skipping the callout using a [Test.isRunningTest()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest) guard.)